# SharePoint 2013 Dynamic Buttom Creation

Tags: apps-development

I have a list with several items that includes a title field and a URL field.  Is it possible to dynamically create buttons using the information in the list?

Same Fields

```
URL:
Title:
Hover Text:
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass the URL field into the button.

Comment: In the demo the code includes a URL.   Is it possible to pass the URL and title of the button from a field in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated column. Switch to number and place some html.

```
=CONCATENATE("<button onclick=""window.open('/sites/....../DispForm.aspx?ID=",[ID],"','_blank','resizable=yes')"">Open Form","</button>")
```

[image]